# How to define if string have a necessary substrings. With regular expression. In one step

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a string, and I want to define if it a correct pathname and that at least one `(\/:)|(^\/?:)` pair of symbols exists and that all in one step.

Correct pathname must include next symbols [a-zA-Z0-9.~!$&'()*+,;=@-_\s:] in each portion, divided by '/'.

For example:

1. `:param1/path1/:param2` - correct, with defining groups {param1, param2}
2. `path1/path2/path3` - incorrect
3. `path1/:param1` - correct, with defining group {param1}

Is it possible to do in one step with a help of regular expression?

Comment: define "correct pathname". For example, is `/Library/Application Support/App Store` "correct"?

Comment: What about `:param1` or `:param1/path/` or `path1/:param1/path1/:param1/path1/path2` ? Do you have examples that should not match? How/where are you using this regex?

Comment: @gog Yes, it's correct

Comment: Why no use regex101.com?

Comment: @Thefourthbird All of your examples are correct, incorrect string is that one which don't have params in the pathname. I just want to recreate routing from the Express.

Comment: @Андрей Something like this https://regex101.com/r/KLG6UR/1 or https://regex101.com/r/XaL05F/1

Comment: @Андрей Did any of them work?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hi, sorry for not responding for so long. The first one isn't work with the next example ':param1/path1/param2', and the second one defines this string '/param1/pa:th/param2/' as valid

Comment: @Андрей So like this https://regex101.com/r/StG7M0/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yeah, it's almost work, except string starts with /

Comment: @Андрей In that case you can make an optional `/` at the beginning https://regex101.com/r/cWSbq1/1